# replacetext backslashed parentheses doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to replace (remove) text in a Google Doc body.
The first one works.
The second one doesn't.  I backslashed the parentheses. But this didn't work.
What am I missing?

```
    body.replaceText("Bevoegd persoon: {%Bevoegd persoon%}","");
    body.replaceText('Naam 2de contact \({%Relatie met secundair contact%}\)','');
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind escaping the parentheses here, what is the point. You already have a string there is no need I can think about that backslash. Could you maybe tried without the `\` and try again?

Comment: In my document body text there is a string "Naam 2de contact ({%Relatie met secundair contact%})".  I want to replace that exact string.

Comment: But when I put this string as a replaceText parameter it will ignore the parentheses because of regex functionality.  So I thought that when I backslash the "(" and the ")" these would be seen as part of the string. But that doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying I made it work. As this is actually handled by a back end server you string needs to escape the backslash so it will be handled as such. Meaning you need to make that backslash double.

In the end the object sent to the server is not a regular expression but a JavaScript plain string.

```
body.replaceText('Naam 2de contact \\({%Relatie met secundair contact%}\\)','');
```